# Invoke-Command to remote call a “java -jar selenium-server-4.0.0-beta-3.jar hub”: powershell terminal control is blocked by java

Tags: java, powershell

I have this `hub.ps1` file:

```
java -jar E:\selenium_grid\selenium-server-4.0.0-beta-3.jar hub
```

which lives on ComputerA

When I am on ComputerA I want to execute the above script on remote ComputerB. So from a PowerShell Terminal in ComputerA I do

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath hub.ps1 -ComputerName ComputerB
```

This indeed runs the java program, but now I cannot continue using the PowerShell Terminal in ComputerA and most importantly, **I cannot close the terminal**, because that would kill the java process on remote ComputerB

I also tried my `hub.ps1` like this

```
javaw -jar E:\selenium_grid\selenium-server-4.0.0-beta-3.jar hub
```

But this does not start javaw at all on remote ComputerB (no error thrown on local ComputerA, I just don't see any javaw process in the background of remote ComputerB)

Also tried this:

```
Start-Process java -ArgumentList "-jar E:\selenium_grid\selenium-server-4.0.0-beta-3.jar hub" -NoNewWindow
```

But again, no java process is spawned on the remote ComputerB while the Invoke-Command call on local ComputerA returns with no error

Is there a way to execute this java program remotely and then safely quit the local powershell terminal?

Comment: Is the remote computer you're trying to run it on, the same user account you're using to invoke the command? Powershell creates a net logon and will launch under the instance of that account, not theirs. You have to run it under their context by using task manager, or invoke it using the system account; psexec can help with this

Comment: ComputerA and ComputerB are using the same user account yes

Comment: Can you verify the process does, or doesn't start with `Get-Process`.